# Zapier API Configuration: send form-data instead of json request body

Tags: zapier

I am setting up a Zap for our application in Zapier.
However, I've run into some trouble having the Zap pass over the data in the correct format.
By default it appears Zapier passes the data as json request body, but our backend only accepts form-data.

Is it possible to configure the Zap to send over form-data instead?
In the code below, I've tried to send the data as both `params` and `body`, but my backend doesn't any of it as form-data:

```
const options = {
  url: '${URL}',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': ${token},
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
  params: {
    'phone': bundle.inputData.phone,
    'email': bundle.inputData.email,
    'dialog': bundle.inputData.dialog,
    'name': bundle.inputData.name
  },
  body: {
    'name': bundle.inputData.name,
    'email': bundle.inputData.email,
    'phone': bundle.inputData.phone,
    'dialog': bundle.inputData.dialog
  }
}

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = z.JSON.parse(response.content);

    // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them

    return results;
  });
```

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by replacing `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` with `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`.